# Intersecting two Dictionaries and getting average scores

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, intersection

I have 2 python dictionaries, and each dictionary has a city name and a score of that city.
I need to compare both the dictionaries in order to find the city with max score.Hence, for this I first take intersection of both the dictionaries to get common cities.This is where I am facing issues.
For example, lets say the two dictionaries are:

```
d1 = {"delhi": 40, "Jaipur": 50, "Gurgaon": 10}
d2 = {"Jaipur(Rajasthan)": 30, "Gurugram(Gurgaon)": 25}
```

Here because of brackets or the city has some extra string along with it, the intersection fails.

So my question is , Is there any way where in if a city is present partly in a string, it is taken into the intersection?

Also, in the end I need to give the city an average score.

I want the end result to be:

```
d3 = {"gurgaon": 17.5((10 + 25) / 2), "jaipur": 40(80 / 2)}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Normalize the dicts first by removing unneeded portions from the keys before performing your intersection logics, especially since the end results do not contain the unneeded portions in the keys.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know, How exactly will i do that? in first case "Jaipur" is outside the bracket and in second case "Gurgaon" is inside the bracket. What would be a generalized way to do this?

Comment: `d3`'s values are invalid. You called floats !

Comment: I am taking average of the values in 2 dictionaries for the common cities. How is it invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create normalized dicts where the keys used for matching are extracted from the original keys. Since names both inside and outside parentheses in the keys of the input dicts can be used for matching, create redundant keys for both names in the normalized dict:

```
import re

n1, n2 = (
    {t.lower(): v for k, v in d.items() for t in re.findall('[^()]+', k)} 
    for d in (d1, d2)
)
print({k: (n1[k] + n2[k]) / 2 for k in n1.keys() & n2.keys()})
```

This outputs:

```
{'gurgaon': 17.5, 'jaipur': 40.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to compare two dicts you can do something like this using the filter function:

```
def get_avg_scores(d1, d2):
    d3 = {}
    for key, item in d1.items():
        # Get match key d1 vs. d2
        d2_similar_key = list(filter(lambda x: key.lower() in x.lower(), d2.keys()))

        #Get match key d2 vs. d1
        d2_similar_key_rev = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in key.lower(), d2.keys()))

        # Keep the simplest key (to avoid bracets in d3)
        if len(d2_similar_key) > 0:
            d3[key] = (item + d2[d2_similar_key[0]])/2
        if len(d2_similar_key_rev) > 0:
            d3[d2_similar_key_rev[0]] = (item + d2[d2_similar_key_rev[0]])/2


    return d3

d3 = get_avg_scores(d1, d2)
```

Comment: Did this run for the above dictionaries I have put? It gave errors for me. Get match key d2 vs. d1 part is empty even though there is a match right?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. Edited!

Comment: This answer assumes that keys in `d1` never contains parentheses, which may not be the case. It is also inefficient to use the `in` operator in a loop, making the time complexity unnecessarily quadratic.

Comment: Well if d1 has parenthesis it's working (since I'm checking d1 vs. d2 and d2 vs.d1). I'm agree that this solution can be inefficient if dictionaries contains thousands of keys. Sometimes doing a unreadable code is hard to maintain in the future. I prefer always to keep it simple if it not takes long time to execute.